# template specialization in C++

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, specialization

I've been trying to understand template specializations. Why is this generating an error (`specialization of 'T foo(T, T) [with T = int]' after instantiation`)

```
template <class T> T foo(T a, T b);

int main()
{
    int x=34, y=54;
    cout<<foo(x, y);
}

template <class T> T foo(T a, T b)
{
    return a+b;
}

template <> int foo<int>(int a, int b)
{
    cout<<"int specialization";
}
```

Comment: Just move the definitions before `main`.

Comment: Sitting in the t rain reading thw question with my android phone but not being able.to answer in time HURTS

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb you are addicted !! seek help ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard demands that all template definitions must be known at the time of instantiation, and that every translation unit see the same definition. Otherwise your program is ill-formed (and in fact no diagnostic is required).

(So to solve this, just put *all* the template definitions at the top of the program.)

Remember that template functions aren't functions, just templates. Think of them as a *code generation* tool.

Answer (score 3):

The explicitly specialized template function `foo()` should be visible before it can be called/Instantiated.

In fact the above rule applies to all Template functions.

**Solution:**
Move the template specialization for `foo()` before your `main()`.

Following should work just fine:

```
template <class T> T foo(T a, T b);

/*Should be visible before instantiation*/
template <> int foo<int>(int a, int b)
{
    cout<<"int specialization";
}

int main()
{
    int x=34, y=54;
    cout<<foo(x, y);
}

template <class T> T foo(T a, T b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that.

What Herb Sutter said:

> If you're writing a function base template, prefer to write it as a
>   single function template that should never be specialized or
>   overloaded, and then implement the function template entirely as a
>   simple handoff to a class template containing a static function with
>   the same signature.

See: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm